# Find the nearest points along the linestring in specified distance limit and order

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have such problem and I would be nice If somebody can help me.
I have points table with GIST index. Those points don't change in time.

I would like to fetch points that are near some given linestring.
Example: Imagine that linestring is the road and points are poi along the road.
I would like to fetch poi's that are in 5 km distance from the given road. I would like to fetch those pois in correct order (driving order along the road). Look at the image:

[image]

For given road from point 1 to 5 i would like to fetch POIs that is in 5 km max from the road and in order from point 1 to 5 along the road. So the result should be:

```
POI_ID
1
5
6
8
9
10
12
13
```

This should tell me what POI I can visit during traveling along the road with minimum cost.

Does anybody have some ideas how to do it with postgres and postgis?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you have geometry columns `geom` that use a projected SRID of meters in tables `road` (LINESTRING) and `poi` (POINT), your query to find all POIs within 5 km of road (where id = 123) should be something like:

```
SELECT poi.*, ST_Distance(road.geom, poi.geom)/1000.0 AS distance_km
FROM road, poi
WHERE road.id = 123 AND ST_DWithin(road.geom, poi.geom, 5000.0)
ORDER BY ST_LineLocatePoint(road.geom, poi.geom),
         ST_Distance(road.geom, poi.geom);
```

The first `ORDER` part with `ST_LineLocatePoint` uses a fraction between 0.0 and 1.0, depending where the point is along the LINESTRING. If the direction of the road is going "the wrong way", then append `DESC` to reverse the order. The second ORDER part is based on distance, which could be used if the point is slightly past the start/end of the LINESTRING (where `ST_LineLocatePoint` would return 0.0 or 1.0, respectively).

This query might also work if you are using the `geography` type with Long/Latitude values, since it automagically calculates metres -- not degrees. Check out docs for more:

- [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html)
- [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)
- [`ST_LineLocatePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html) (or `ST_Line_Locate_Point` for older versions of PostGIS)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this will not work because order will be wrong. If road (linestring) with id=123 has points 1,2,3,4 i would like to fetch points (pois) in order that You will be passing along road so first the closest poi near the point 1, then 2, 3 and ending by the last point of linestring 4.

Comment: I will try my friend :) Also I updated question to be more understandable.

Comment: very nice answer. Thank you very much. Any ideas how I can match the selected POI's with points on the lineString?

Comment: @cecemel convert the LineString to a MultiPoint to find the closest vertext, [like here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/111714/1872).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could benefit from the KNN-GIST feature from last summer's PostgreSQL 9.1 release and supported by PostGIS version 2.0.

http://blog.opengeo.org/2011/09/28/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/